# Scaling plots matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I got 2 files with data and am trying to create a figure using matplotlib:

data1.csv:

```
T1,T2,Energy
-10.0,-10.0,-135.17209154
-9.0,-9.0,-135.15961763
-8.0,-8.0,-135.12933854
-7.0,-7.0,-135.08764644
-6.0,-6.0,-135.04017015
-5.0,-5.0,-134.9917753
-4.0,-4.0,-134.9465778
-3.0,-3.0,-134.90793353
-2.0,-2.0,-134.8782808
-1.0,-1.0,-134.86001462
0.0,0.0,-134.85401885
1.0,1.0,-134.86001461
2.0,2.0,-134.87828068
3.0,3.0,-134.90793366
4.0,4.0,-134.94657765
5.0,5.0,-134.99177495
6.0,6.0,-135.04017025
7.0,7.0,-135.08764629
8.0,8.0,-135.12933843
9.0,9.0,-135.15961751
10.0,10.0,-135.17209131
```

data2.csv:

```
T1,T2,Energy
-10.0,-10.0,-117.71068713
-9.0,-9.0,-117.80680053
-8.0,-8.0,-117.87570934
-7.0,-7.0,-117.92318137
-6.0,-6.0,-117.95416633
-5.0,-5.0,-117.97304758
-4.0,-4.0,-117.98349172
-3.0,-3.0,-117.9884913
-2.0,-2.0,-117.99017179
-1.0,-1.0,-117.99078073
0.0,0.0,-117.99109191
1.0,1.0,-117.99083075
2.0,2.0,-117.99029791
3.0,3.0,-117.98887774
4.0,4.0,-117.98440979
5.0,5.0,-117.97484573
6.0,6.0,-117.95727936
7.0,7.0,-117.92813366
8.0,8.0,-117.88311587
9.0,9.0,-117.81736874
10.0,10.0,-117.72521723
```

I wrote a script:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FRAME1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
FRAME2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

FRAME1.columns = ['T1', 'T2', 'ENERGY']
FRAME2.columns = ['T1', 'T2', 'ENERGY']

FRAME1 = FRAME1.iloc[::-1]
FRAME2 = FRAME2.iloc[::-1]


plt.plot(FRAME1['T1'],FRAME1['ENERGY'], marker = 'o', label='1')
plt.plot(FRAME2['T1'],FRAME2['ENERGY'], marker = 'o', label='2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.ylim =  np.arange(-140.854019, -118.991092, 0.002)

plt.xlabel(r'$\Delta T$')
plt.ylabel('Eint')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

However I struggle with setting up a right scale. 
[image]

Pretty much my plots seem to be almost linear. I want to change a scale and show them in a real parabola shape.

Comment: You can change the scale with `plt.ylim`, but if you want to plot both graphs on the same picture, your scale will be similar to shown on the picture (as minimum of y has to be near -135 and maximum near -117). You can assign different values for `ylim` but most probably only one graph will be on the picture after that. What kind of figure do you like to obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `twinx()` axes method, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

FRAME1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
FRAME2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

FRAME1.columns = ['T1', 'T2', 'ENERGY']
FRAME2.columns = ['T1', 'T2', 'ENERGY']

FRAME1 = FRAME1.iloc[::-1]
FRAME2 = FRAME2.iloc[::-1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

h1, = ax1.plot(FRAME1['T1'], FRAME1['ENERGY'], color="b", marker = 'o', label='1')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
h2, = ax2.plot(FRAME2['T1'],FRAME2['ENERGY'], color="g", marker = 'o', label='2')

ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\Delta T$')
ax1.set_ylabel('Eint')
ax2.set_ylabel('Eint')
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.2f'))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.2f'))
ax1.grid(True)
ax2.grid(True)
labels = [lb.get_label() for lb in (h1,h2)]
ax1.legend((h1,h2), labels)

plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

And obtains:

[image]

For more info check [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) about twinx